# How to export data from firestore database emulator

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

In the official firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import) you can find how to export firestore data from your Google cloud account.

I'm using emulators locally. Is there a way to export firestore data from the emulator?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a proper documentation for importing/exporting Firestore data from the emulator you may refer to this link [Export and import emulator data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#export_and_import_emulator_data).